# Spring mvc url parameter

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I cannot display may restaurant.
I.ve got my controller class:

```
@Controller
public class RestaurantController extends MultiActionController{

    private RestaurantDAO restaurantDAO;

    public void setRestaurantDAO(RestaurantDAO restaurantDAO) {
        this.restaurantDAO = restaurantDAO;
    }


    @RequestMapping("/restaurant/{restaurantId}")
    public ModelAndView restaurantid(@PathVariable("contactId") int id, 
         HttpServletRequest request,
         HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {

       Restaurant restaurant = restaurantDAO.findRestaurantById(id);
       ModelMap modelMap = new ModelMap();
       modelMap.addAttribute("restaurant", restaurant);
       return new ModelAndView("restaurant", modelMap);
    }
}
```

im my jsp just:

```
<c:out value="${restaurant.name }"
```

in my spring-servlet.xml:

```
<bean name="/restaurant/**" class="web.RestaurantController" >
<property name="restaurantDAO" ref="myRestaurantDAO"/> 
</bean>
```

Answer (score 5):

Because you mixed up `restaurantId` and `contactId`

```
@RequestMapping("/restaurant/{restaurantId}")
public ModelAndView restaurantid(@PathVariable("contactId") ...
```

I guess when you change `@PathVariable("contactId")` to `@PathVariable("restaurantId")` it will work.

And add `@RequestMapping("/restaurant/**")` to your controller:

```
 @RequestMapping("/restaurant/**")
 @Controller
 public class RestaurantController extends MultiActionController{
```

BTW: What is a MultiActionController?

Comment: My mistake, sorry. But it also still doesn't work

The requested resource (/RestFinderWebApp/restaurant/48) is not available.

Comment: add @RequestMapping("/restaurant/**") to your controller and have a look at the found mappings (spring will print them on INFO level at startup)

Comment: I changed like you told me to do, but it srill doenst work. MultiActionController: import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.multiaction.MultiActionController;

Comment: @zax: Remove the MultiActionController inheritance. MultiActionController belongs to the not annotation driven MCV style